# Using underscore in Angular to find something within an Array

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, underscore.js

I'm working on an angular project where I have access to a JSON feed of user data.  Normally, I would call that as a service within a controller by simply doing:

```
userFactory.get(function (data) {
    $scope.results = data;
}
```

However, in one of my controllers, I need to write an `if` statement that checks a nested array to see if the `type` field has a certain value. In the example below, I'm looking for `"type" : "yep"`.

```
{
   "id": 3,
   "data": stuff,
   "following": [
      {
         "id": 213,
         "type": "nope",
      },
      {
         "id": 324,
         "type": "nope",
      },
      {
         "id": 532,
         "type": "yep",
      }
   ],
}
```

What I need to do is search through the following object to find out whether there is any instance of `"type" : "yep"`.  I figure this is doable with underscore, but I'm not sure how.  I was thinking of something along the lines of:

```
userFactory.get(function (user) {
  $scope.user=user;
  if (underscore find if value exsist){
  // do stuff
  }
  else
  {
  //do other stuff
  }
)};
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var data = {
    "id": 3,
        "data": 'stuff',
        "following": [{
        "id": 213,
            "type": "nope",
    }, {
        "id": 324,
            "type": "nope",
    }, {
        "id": 532,
            "type": "yep",
    }],
};
var result = _.find(data.following, function (item) {
    return item.type === "yep";
});
if(result)
console.log(result);
else
    //do your stuff.
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7Z5VL/)**

Comment: perfect!  What is the difference between _.some and _.find?  I actually half figured this out with _.some and it also seems to work fine.

Comment: some return boolean and find return list items. Some will be faster.